# Is lua a dynamically typed language?

Tags: types, lua, torch

Is lua a dynamically typed language?

If  it is, why is there a difference between normal Tensor and CudaTensor?

For example:

```
a = torch.Tensor(5,5):zero()
```

and

```
b = torch.CudaTensor(5,5):zero()
```

Comment: Yes, Lua is dynamically typed language. Type associated with the value, and not with a variable. Your question sounds more like "If Lua is dynamically typed language, then why there's difference between table and string".

Comment: its like the 30th line in the Lua manual. you know the expression RTFM? Is it too much to ask? Can't you at least read the chapter Basic Concepts of a programming language you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1

Chapter 2: **Basic Concepts**:

2.1 Values and Types:

> Lua is a dynamically typed language. This means that variables do not
>   have types; only values do. There are no type definitions in the
>   language. All values carry their own type.

Tensor and CudaTensor have nothing to do with Lua btw.. They're part of the third party library Torch. I haven't worked with torch yet but a torch.Tensor is most likely a Lua table or userdata.

Torch may provide it's own type() function to emulate more "types" though.